# Wget from HTTPS url using user/password -still getting 400 error

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, https, wget

I'm trying to run Wget for a certain HTTP url, also using http-user and http-password command line options (tried the --user and --password, same results).
Using the --no-check-certificate options as well
so basically running this line :

```
wget --no-check-certificate --http-user=user --http-password=password https://url.com
```

I'm getting this response :

```
Connecting to url.com|10.11.10.98|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify url.com's certificate, issued by `/C=IL/ST=url.com':
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2012-01-18 15:13:53 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

Please advise

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the option dashes for both --http-user and --http-password:

`wget --server-response --no-check-certificate --http-user=user --http-password=password https://url.com`

The fact that this appears to "look like" a URL to wget may be the reason it uses HTTP and not HTTPS for the real URL as well.

Comment: For single test requests like this, I can recommend using `wget -O /dev/null -d [rest of options]`, this will show you useful debug output, including header exchanges between the client and the server, so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @adaptr, that was my mistake in retyping the command line for the question as the copy-paste didn't work.. :)